# gettext constantly broken after MacPorts upgrade

Tags: macports, gettext

I use MacPorts on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.
This issue has been there for a year:
whenever I upgrade MacPorts:

```
sudo port selfupdate
```

this seems to work fine. But then running:

```
sudo port upgrade outdated
```

it always fails at gettext:

```
Error: org.macports.activate for port gettext returned: 
Error: Failed to install gettext
Please see the log file for port gettext for details:
    /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_devel_gettext/gettext/main.log
Error: The following dependencies were not installed: gettext
Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
To report a bug, follow the instructions in the guide:
    http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets
```

Then if I run any `port` commands at all, I get:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libintl.8.dylib
  Referenced from: /bin/sh
  Reason: image not found
```

Fortunately I have another Mac so usually if I copy the same dylib back from there I'd be fine afterwards.

I don't believe that this was a bug that was hanging for years. It must have been something I've been doing wrong. Question is what?